# Why does my FPS drop dramatically in Opportunity?

Tags: borderlands-2

For some reason whenever I'm in Opportunity and I look around at all the buildings, my FPS drops to below 40, sometimes 30. Opportunity isn't the only place it happens, but it's most notable there.

My PC specs:

- AMD Phenom II X4 965 @ 3.68Ghz
- Radeon HD 7950
- 16Gb DDR3 RAM
- 128Gb SSD

As you can see this is a pretty high end PC. I have updated all my drivers, so please don't tell me to.

Note: I just noticed this happening even more in Thousand Cuts, if you go to the Hyperion barrier and look over the Slab fortress.

Comment: It's probably just one of the more CPU intensive areas. I notice lag in the first part of Caustic Caverns but no where else, personally.

Comment: So you think upgrading my CPU would fix it? I'm going to get a AMD Piledriver when it comes out.

Comment: What are your video/graphics settings?

Comment: @galacticninja Everything max except for PhysX (low)

Comment: RE upgrading your CPU I doubt kinda it, I'm OC'd at 4 Ghz and a Raedon 6950. Any upgrade beyond that will cost you a fair amount of dough, and most games don't seem to take advantage of 8 cores. I'm sure some degree of amazing CPU and GPU would fix it, but I think it'd have to be a very substantial upgrade.

Comment: Borderlands 2 is actually very CPU dependent. I looked at some benchmarks, and a better CPU can give an extra 20 fps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have PhysX set to higher than 'low' in your video settings? If yes, try setting it to low as you might have a large performance hit due to the fact that the PhysX would be CPU-bound if you have an AMD GPU. (Source: [PC Gaming Wiki; Borderlands 2 - PhysX](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderlands_2#PhysX))

I'd also try setting the framerate option to 'Smoothed 22-62'. What it does is try to maintain your frame rate between 22-62, automatically adjusting the engine (graphics, effects, draw distance, etc) on-the-fly, to try to maintain this frame rate in parts where your PC starts to drop the frame rate below the minimum (22fps). Source: [Steam forum post on 'Capped 60, smoothed 22-62, or unlimited+vsync on?' thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=32850754&postcount=8)

If that still doesn't work for you, try changing the framerate setting to 'Unlimited' instead. Then, try changing *MinDesiredFrameRate* from 35 to 60 in *WillowEngine.ini* in the USERS directory: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\Config\`. It may result in the expected performance from high-powered hardware. (Source: [PC Gaming Wiki; 'Borderlands 2 - Microstutter on Powerful Rigs'](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderlands_2#Microstutter_on_Powerful_Rigs))

Comment: I have PhysX on low. Turning down the graphics automatically isn't an option, as it doesn't fix the issue. I'll try the third one.

Comment: Tweaking that setting seems to have greatly improved my performance. Thanks!

Comment: @ryansworld10 I'm glad it helped. By the way, what setting did you set the framerate option to? Did you set it to 'Unlimited', or another option?

Comment: I have it set to cap at 60, Vsync on. I know it can hurt performance slightly, but screen tearing is so freaking annoying.

Comment: It looks like I'm still having the frame drop issue when looking at large areas. After experimenting, I just noticed that this happens regardless of my graphics settings. Therefore, it is probably my CPU. That third fix did fix frame drops during combat though :)